# SQL Server Cursor vs WHILE loop

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server: when you need to loop a set of data, is there a benefit of using a SQL Server cursor. Or is using a WHILE loop (see below) just the same.

This assumes that you want to do something that cannot be done in a set-based way

I ask because the WHILE loop seems clearer and easier to understand.

```
-- loop through a table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LoopingSet;
CREATE TABLE #LoopingSet (RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1), DatabaseName sysname);
INSERT INTO #LoopingSet (DatabaseName) SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 ORDER BY name;

DECLARE @i INT = (SELECT MIN(RowID) FROM #LoopingSet);
DECLARE @n INT = (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM #LoopingSet);
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname = '';

WHILE (@i <= @n)
BEGIN
    SELECT @DatabaseName = DatabaseName FROM #LoopingSet WHERE RowID = @i;
    PRINT @DatabaseName; -- do something here
    SELECT @i = MIN(RowID) FROM #LoopingSet WHERE RowID > @i;
END;
```

Comment: I'd ask do you need to loop at all. I find that when people say that they "need" to loop, they actually mean that they don't know how to achieve their goal in a set-based way.

Comment: A `CURSOR` still uses a `WHILE` loop though, so I'm not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: I prefer a cursor, for a couple of reasons: 1) the fetching of next row in while loop might be slower than cursor fetch. in your code you have a min row id which needs to traverse some data + the actual fetch 2) Sometimes rows doesn't have a continuious ids, so the fetching looks ugly and it's easier to get it wrong and turn loop into eternal loop 3) sometimes you don't wanna copy data 4) updatable cursors are easier to write than while loops. This is very subjective opinion though.

Comment: Downsides of cursors: 1) the locking and loading cursor needs some understanding 2) Non-local cursor needs to be closed explicitly 3) People on stackoverflow tend to dislike them 4) And last but not least, people tend to use cursor when you can solve the problem by set-based solutions

Comment: Eh, I don't think it's just [so] that "dislike" them, @siggemannen, but I also think that it's people dislike them being used *incorrectly*, not that they dislike like `CURSOR`s specifically. There are times for a `CURSOR`, but looping through your rows to get a running total isn't one of them. ;)

Comment: In your case you don't even have an index on RowID - the cursor should be able to remember where the scan had got up to physically and find the next row more efficiently without having to scan the whole table each time

Comment: @ThomA yeah agree, it was mostly pulling some legs :P But updated the answer a bit now!

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/328771/sql-cursor-vs-while-loop) on different forums. It causes duplicate effort for the parties involved.

Comment: A cursor is usually more efficient than a manual `WHILE` loop. In your case your `WHILE` is very inefficient, as you are doing two lookups on the table. But usually you  don't need a cursor or a loop at all, just use some kind of string aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I ask because the WHILE loop seems clearer and easier to understand.

Is it clearer and easier to understand?

```sql
DECLARE 
    @Name sysname,
    @Names CURSOR,
    @Rows integer;

SET @Names = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT [name] 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE database_id > 4 
    ORDER BY [name] ASC;

OPEN @Names;

SET @Rows = @@CURSOR_ROWS;

WHILE @Rows > 0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Names INTO @Name;
    PRINT @Name;
    SET @Rows -= 1;
END;
```

It's a subjective question but objectively, your implementation of a cursor is a little less efficient than using the built-in facility.